# ERR Failed to find file(s) for depdency reference

Tags: extjs, build, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have added extra js file Fileup.js for file upload functionality.It works fine,but while building trigger this error.I have put  Fileup.js directly under extensions folder.Any help?

```
 4:07 [ERR] Failed to find file(s) for depdency reference
 project/app/view/phone/testing.js::ClassRequire::Ext.Fileup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sencha.cfg` I have set this and it fixed the issue

```
app.classpath=${app.dir}/app.js,${app.dir}/app,${app.dir}/touch/src
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to declare necessary js files in your `app.json`:

```
"js": [
     // the framework here includes sencha-touch.js, bootstrap.js, app.js, etc...
         {
             "path": "(path to your js file)"
         }
     ],
```